# android timer service

Tags: android

i need to make a timer service and bind it to an activity... i cant do it...
can someone share an example of such a thing or a tutorial...
ive already gone through
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.html
and the adnroid developer documention guide
please help
:/

Comment: What do you mean with "timer service"? What is your goal. Do you want to write a service that notifies listening apps at regular intervals?

Answer (score 0):

By quickly looking over the BluetoothChatService code you mention, I've seen that the communication between the activity and the service goes through the Android **Handlers**.

Try to take a look on the developer documentation on how to use them. Here are also some quite good resources:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html
- https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html